# Angular Datepicker showing seperately month and year

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am trying to find an angular date-picker that looks like the image below:

[image: 1]

Does anyone know any datepicker that is similar to this or whether I could use Angular Material Datepicker to create something similar to the image attached?

Comment: Hi, did the answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use **Angular Material Datepicker** to create something similar to the image attached.

You can refer `Datepicker with custom calendar header` in this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/onqdvjgpmkx?file=src/app/datepicker-custom-header-example.ts) link from Angular material datepicker

Modified [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgw9ew?file=src/app/header-template.html) as per your requirement

You need to provide header template to the `MatDatePicker`

Main changes I made compared to original stackblitz provided by angular material

**header-template.html**

```
<div class="example-header">
    <span class="example-header-label">{{monthLabel}}</span>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="previousClicked('month')">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
      </button>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="nextClicked('month')">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
      </button>
    <span class="example-header-label">{{yearLabel}}</span>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-double-arrow" (click)="previousClicked('year')">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
      </button>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-double-arrow" (click)="nextClicked('year')">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
      </button>
</div>
```

**datepicker-custom-header-example.ts**

```
get monthLabel() {
  return this._dateAdapter
    .format(this._calendar.activeDate, this._dateFormats.display.monthYearLabel)
    .toLocaleUpperCase().split(" ")[0];
}

get yearLabel() {
  return this._dateAdapter
    .format(this._calendar.activeDate, this._dateFormats.display.monthYearLabel).split(" ")[1];
}
```

And you can play with original stackblitz provided by Angular material datepicker

Comment: @IraklisAnastasiou Glad to hear that it helped you ;)